# C pointers to characters

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am misunderstanding something about C pointers:

```
void putString(char* StringPtr, int length){
  for(int i=0; i< length; i++)       
  {                   
    USART_send(*StringPtr);      
    StringPtr++;
  }
}

void parseMsg(char* in_string, int str_len) {
  int i = 0;
  putString(in_string, str_len);
  for(i = 0; i <= str_len; i++) 
  {
    char* temp_pt = &in_string[i];
    putString(temp_pt, 1);
  }
}

int main(int arg) {
  char* myChar = "abcdefg";
  parseMsg(myChar, 7);
}
```

**EDIT:**
In `parseMsg`, when I call the first `putString`, it works great. When I try to loop through to print each one separately, it does not. `USART_send` just spits out the char to my terminal.

Comment: Ask your compiler to give you all the warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using GCC). It will be unhappy with the assignment to `temp` in `tester`.

Comment: Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch, I already am, that's how I found this error in the first place.

Comment: What does `USART_send` do? And how does the prototype look like?

Comment: The massive edit invalidates the answer ... that's not the way to do things here. In your final code, `for(i = 0; i <= str_len; i++) ` is off by one. Learn your idioms: `for i = 0; i < count; i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `test[i]` is of type `char` not of type `char *`.

You can either assign to char:

```
 char temp = test[i];
```

or take its address:

```
 char *temp = &test[i];
```

Comment: Sort of. `"a"` with double quotes is a pointer to a string of characters. It will even add a `\0` to the end. (You will see that `myChar[1]` holds the value `0`.)

Comment: Eh... `"a"` is a literal string, which is a pointer to a constant array of `char`-s terminated by a zero byte.... It is not a pointer to a string...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, I didn't quite know how to answer the question. Of course, it depends on how you define "string" :).

Comment: @BartFriederichs, Thanks! I updated my question to be more specific to my actual problem if you want to take a look.

Comment: @BartFriederichs - for info: "a" is a static array of char (not const, though); in an expression it becomes a pointer to the first character of a string. A string is defined in the standard as a sequence of characters including a `\0`, but a string literal can hold several strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your line `char* temp = test[i];` is wrong. It makes a pointer called temp and makes it point at an address somewhere between byte 0 and byte `255` in your computer's memory. That is almost certainly a very bad thing. You probably meant char `temp = test[i];` That makes a char called temp and assigns to it the value of `test[i]`. Also note that `test[2]` would also not be valid because `myChar` is a string with only 1 character plus the `null` terminator.